# How to replace instances of repeating characters inside strings with regex?

Tags: regex

I need to specifically highlight instances of the character `a`, but only if they are inside a double quote, `""`.

Eg, given this string: `"a"`. I should find the `a`. Given this string `"blah"`, I should also find the `a`. The following should all be found: `"I am a good boy."`, `"I am an aavark"`, `"1224a"`. I only want to highlight the `a`'s and nothing else if possible.

I've tried to use this regex to detect for characters inside the string:

`(?<=")([a])(?=")`, but this only matches single instances of a. I've also tried putting `a*` inside the middle `()`, but it doesn't work as I would expect.

This is working in notepad++ trying to find and using regex. I have a lot of JS files, and I want to find all strings that uses a specific character. Doesn't matter how many repeating, as long as they are between the `""`.

Comment: Are you trying to identify strings having a repeated character, highlight such characters in matching strings, or both?

Comment: If it's just ascii letters, you'd be better off in a loop using each letter to find and record the sub string position's in a hash/array type.

Comment: This is working in notepad++ trying to find and using regex.

Comment: What is your intention? You can easily identify groups of `a` with a simple `".*?(a+).*?"` search.

Comment: @zwer, that highlights all strings with an `a` inside of it. I need to specifically hightlight instances of the character `a`, but only if they are inside a double quote, `""`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm trying to highlight repeating characters or repeating characters (let's say `a` in this scenario), that are inside of strings ONLY. Not highlight whole string, but just the characters. I need to find and replace them with something else.

Comment: What is the replacement?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The replacement can be anything. Say `b`, for instance. I can do that part via the find and replace on my text editor, I just need to match it right now.

Comment: You need to use some language that will be able to run a regex replace operation with a callback. If you need to do it on 1 file in NPP, you may use a PythonScript solution. If you are interested, I can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp matches witch two or more "a" consecutives: aa+
Correction. this is the complete regex:    ".*aa+.*"
..

UPDATE
You can use perl or linux shell commands.

For example using the awk linux shell command:

a) Change groups of two or more "a" with "x" in quoting strings:
`awk '/".*aa+.*"/ {gsub(/aa+/, "x")}; {print} ' in.txt > out.txt`

b) Change all matches of simple "a" with "x", in cuoting strings:
`awk '/".*a.*"/ {gsub(/a/, "x")}; {print} ' in.txt > out.txt`

- Source file in.txt content:
  hola
  una casa
  de veraaano
  "la cacaa vaaa de"
  caracola
  "aa"
  "coco"
- Result in  out.txt file. Case a):

hola
una casa
de veraaano
"la cacx vx de"
caracola
"x"
"coco"

- Result in  out.txt file. Case b):

hola
una casa
de veraaano
"lx cxcxx vxxx de"
caracola
"xx"
"coco"

Comment: That only works for "a" or "aa". Not "I am an aadvark". I need all a's no matter if they're standalone or in a sentence.

Comment: For example matches in line 2 and 3 bellow.

Comment: hola
1. una casa
2. de ver**aaa**no
3. la cac**aa** v**aaa** de
4. caracola

Comment: And this match with all line that contain any group of repeated "a": .*aa+.*

Comment: ... complete with " characters:                                                                 **".*aa+.*"**

Comment: You can use perl or linux shell commands.

- For example using the awk linux shell command. Replace groups of two or more "a"  in quoting line, with "x"

 `awk '{ if(match($0,/".*aa+.*"/ ) != 0) gsub(/aa+/, "x"); print}' in.txt > out.txt`

 - Source file in.txt content:
hola
una casa
de veraaano
"la cacaa vaaa de"
caracola
"aa"

 - Result in  out.txt file:
hola
una casa
de veraaano
"la cacx vx de"
caracola
"x"

Comment: Answer updating.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated application of the following regex meets the requirements:

```
^([^"]*("[^"a]*"[^"]*)*"[^"a]*)a+
```

The first capture group is present for convenient replacement in Notepad++ using `\1x`. Note that this will replace sequences of `a` with a single `X`. Drop the trailing `+` in the regex if character-by-character replacement is needed.

The regex is anchored at the beginning of the text and skips over sequences of unquoted text and quoted material not containing an `a`. Text portions enclosed in matched double quotes must not include an escaped double quote (eg. `bla bla "bla \"bla"`).

There can be no solution that is local in the sense that it does neither include a subpattern for the complete prefix of the `a` sequence to be matched nor require additional bookkeeping/processing in the regex-hosting environment - the number of double quotes up to the matching site needs to be checked to be even.

One way out and towards a programmatic solution are regex variants that allow for anchoring the previous match ( see this [list of supporting environments](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G) ).